# Year returned by Date() in excel is incorrect

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

On applying the formula

```
=IFERROR(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"-")
```

for `30/09/0201`(a text value in A1), I was expecting `0201-09-30` but excel returned `2101-09-30`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Excel Dates starts from `January 1, 1900` but you are expecting something which is beyond

Comment: `0201-09-30` is not a valid date in Excel.

Comment: Using `TEXTJOIN()` will give you the desired output: `=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("-",,RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"-")`

Comment: ```=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("-",,RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"-")``` This worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, please! you can add.

Answer (score 1):

This is behaving as per [the documentation of `DATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349):

> **Year**    Required. The value of the year argument can include one to four digits. Excel interprets the year argument according to the date system your computer is using. By default, Microsoft Excel for Windows uses the 1900 date system, which means the first date is January 1, 1900.
>
> > Tip: Use four digits for the year argument to prevent unwanted results. For example, "07" could mean "1907" or "2007." Four digit years prevent confusion.
>
> - If year is between 0 (zero) and 1899 (inclusive), Excel adds that value to 1900 to calculate the year. For example, DATE(108,1,2) returns January 2, 2008 (1900+108).
> - If year is between 1900 and 9999 (inclusive), Excel uses that value as the year. For example, DATE(2008,1,2) returns January 2, 2008.
> - If year is less than 0 or is 10000 or greater, Excel returns the #NUM! error value.

Your year is 201, so it falls into the first category - adding 1900, to give a value of 2101.

Comment: I am dealing with years prior to 1900 and in that case how can I handle such dates?

Comment: @Parvathi well, you might consider subtracting 1900 and see what that does. Then, if not consider what else you could do.

Comment: @Parvathi Depending on what you want to do with those dates, in the "Excel" world you could construct a text string as indicated in a different answer; you could use either VBA or Power Query, both of which handle dates from the year 1 to year 9999. Or you could write a custom function. Be aware that neither of these has native functions to handle the 1752 calendar change (from Julian to Gregorian calendar) but merely assume the Gregorian calendar back to the year 1. You would have to write a custom function to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by OP to add the commented solution in answers:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("-",,RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),"-")
```

---

The formula used in OP, wont work since in Excel Dates starts from `January 1, 1900` hence using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> the desired output can be achieved.

---

Comment: Note that this won't do the same sort of validation as before - so an input of "99/99/2000" will come out as "2000-99-99" instead of "-". Maybe that's okay - just worth being aware of.

Comment: Sir, understood and thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: Could use a `LET(` for the right, middle and left part and if the right isn't part of the excel usable years, test the date with a working year, if no error, do the textjoin, if error give "-". Might have to check if the year is divisible by 4 for 29/2/xxxx encounters though.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya There is another issue that the filter doesn't work with year categories when the TESTJOIN() is introduced. But with DATE() filtering was possible for years.

Comment: @Parvathi I think that is a different question. You need to raise the question as a new post, showing a screenshot or markdown data. And it certainly won't work as dates and times are stored as numbers in excel while the one you have requested for reads as a text.